# Load gem installed during execution of ruby script

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When try to load a gem that is installed midway a ruby script execution that has already load gems, the installed gem cannot be found. I looked at the source code for `Gem::Specification` and on the reader for the `all` class variable, there is a scan for `gemspec` files that is cached.

Resetting this variable with `Gem::Specification.all = nil` works, but it comes with this comment:

```
##
# Sets the known specs to +specs+. Not guaranteed to work for you in
# the future. Use at your own risk. Caveat emptor. Doomy doom doom.
# Etc etc.
#
#--
# Makes +specs+ the known specs
# Listen, time is a river
# Winter comes, code breaks
#
# -- wilsonb

def self.all= specs
  @@all = specs
end
```

I wonder if there's a better way.

Comment: did you try `Gem::Specification.reset`?